# String should get split on the right side of the page

Tags: c#, string, split, arrays

I have a path saved in string (datn1, datn2) and want to print the path on a page. So I have to look, if the string is too long for the width of the page and if it is too long, it should begin with a new line.

First of all I split the string and saved it in a string array:

```
String datn1 = dateiName1, datn2 = dateiName1;
char[] Trennzeichen = { '\\' };
String[] folders1 = datn1.Split(Trennzeichen);
String[] folders2 = datn2.Split(Trennzeichen);
```

I also have the margins of the page in variables:

```
float leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin, width, height;
```

Now I want to add a new string to parts of the string array and look, if it's on the page. When it reaches the right site it should make a new line... how can i do that?
my idea:

```
string path_new;
for (int i = 0; i <= folders1.Length; i++)
{
   If()//How can i say that he should look if the string is inside the margins?
   {
      path_new= folders1[i]+"//";
   }
   else
   {
      path_new= "\n" + folders1[i]+ "//";
   }
}
```

Comment: Is site in your question referring to a website? What framework are you using to build the website in c#? If it's a website, what use is it to calculate the length of the string on the server? What if someone has a lower resolution or resizes the window?

Comment: no i suggested the right side of a page, which i want to print... pagesize --> a4

Comment: It's clearer now but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you writing the path to a file that you print out or by what means are you printing your output? Additional question: Won't this depend on the font and its size?

Comment: i want to print the path on a page and because it is to long i have to split it. yes it depends on the font and size. because of that i want a query if the string is inside the margins and if not it should begin with a new line. uptonow it looks like this: http://abload.de/img/problem2bkz6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i found a solution:

```
 private void DrawGraphic(Graphics g) 
{                    
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
    String datn1 = dateiName1, datn2 = dateiName2;
                char[] Trennzeichen = { '\\' };
                String[] folders1, folders2;
                if (vergl.X == 1)
                   folders1 = datn1.Split(Trennzeichen);
                else
                   folders1 = new String[0];
                if (vergl.Y == 1)
                   folders2 = datn2.Split(Trennzeichen);
                else
                   folders2 = new String[0];

                if (pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Landscape == false)
                {
                  string path_new = "";
                  string path_new2 = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < folders1.Length; i++)
                {
                 string path_temp = path_new + folders1[i] + "//";
                 System.Drawing.Size size_path_temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(path_temp, new Font("Verdana", 8f));  // get size of string path_temp (in pixel)    
                 double size_path_temp_width = Convert.ToDouble(size_path_temp.Width); 
                 double variable = Convert.ToDouble(rightMargin.ToString())*96/25.4d; //96 = dpi Anzahl

                if (size_path_temp_width < variable)
                 {
                  path_new += folders1[i] + "//";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  path_new += System.Environment.NewLine + folders1[i] + "//";
                 }
                }

            for (int i = 0; i < folders2.Length; i++)
            {
              string path_temp = path_new2 + folders2[i] + "//";
              System.Drawing.Size size_path_temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(path_temp, new Font("Verdana", 8f));  // get size of string path_temp (in pixel)    
              double size_path_temp_width = Convert.ToDouble(size_path_temp.Width);
              double variable = Convert.ToDouble(rightMargin.ToString()) * 96 / 25.4d; //96 = dpi

         if (size_path_temp_width < variable)
         {
          path_new2 += folders2[i] + "//";
         }
         else
         {
          path_new2 += System.Environment.NewLine + folders2[i] + "//";
         }
        } 
 g.DrawString(path_new, new Font("Verdana", 8f), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), leftMargin, topMargin+10);
 g.DrawString(path_new2, new Font("Verdana", 8f), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 20, topMargin + 10 + bmp1.Height / 6 + 25);
}
```

dateiName1 and dateiName2 is a string in which the paths are saved.
vergl.X and vergl.Y checks if there is a path read in